# Download a File in a Batch File

Tags: windows, download, batch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Download a file via HTTP from a script in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/129269/download-a-file-via-http-from-a-script-in-windows)

I've never done any scripting on Windows but now I need to write a batch file that downloads a file off the Internet (amongst other things). If it was Linux I would use `wget`.

Is there a built-in executable that will download a file to a given directory? This needs to run on Windows XP.

Comment: What makes you think you can't use wget on windows?  See http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm.

Comment: There is a somewhat built-in HTTP download command. It comes with the resource kit and it is called bitsadmin.exe .   FTP download , on the other hand, can be done with a basic DOS script.

Answer (score 4):

There is no builtin.  But [wget](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) works just fine in batch files.

Comment: thats wrong, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa362813(VS.85).aspx is part of the system since windows xp.

Comment: @akira -  wow! i didn't know about that one.  it turns out that i only installed half of the support tools and i was missing this one among some others.  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Wget has a [Windows version](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) as well. I assume you know how to use it. Besides Wget, there is also [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html) (A Windows version is available [here](http://fileforum.betanews.com/detail/cURL-for-Windows/966899018/1), but I haven't used it). You can give it a try.