# Why doesn't the bitsadmin.exe download manager work for me?

Tags: windows-xp, batch-file, download

Why does this bitsadmin command fail?

```
bitsadmin.exe /transfer myDownloadJob /download /priority normal http://mirror.anl.gov/pub/ubuntu-iso/DVDs/ubuntu/8.04/release/FOOTER.html c:\Temp
```

It seems that it should work, but it gives me this error:

```
BITSADMIN version 2.0 [ 6.6.2600.2180 ]
BITS administration utility.
(C) Copyright 2000-2004 Microsoft Corp.

Unable to add file - 0x80070005
Access is denied.
```

NOTE:  I am using bitsadmin.exe  from this file:  WindowsXP-KB838079-SupportTools-ENU.exe

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The parameter at the end, `C:\Temp`, is the path of a *file*, not a *folder*.  If you had nothing at `C:\Temp`, meaning no file or directory at that path, the remote file would be downloaded to a file named `C:\Temp` (no extension). If you have a directory at `C:\Temp`, you get the access denied message, because a new file cannot be created at that path.

In short, you need to change the parameter at the end to a full file path, something like `C:\Temp\footer.html`.

Comment: It also doesn't accept relative paths for some reason, so it really needs to be an absolute file path.