# Which tools bundled with windows can be used to upload a text file to the web?

Tags: windows, command-line, java, batch-file

I have a text file, and I want to post its contents to a webserver. I would like to do it using applications that come bundled with Windows. I don't mind writing a batch script to do it. But I don't want to add new software for this task.

In unix land there is curl for this task.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Edit: This needs to work in Windows XP and Windows 7

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/129269/download-a-file-via-http-from-a-script-in-windows/129286#129286

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having found no cross-platform solution across Windows XP, Windows 7 and Windows server 2003, we took the approach of a Java client using the [Apache HTTP Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) libraries.

#### Compiling:

> javac -cp "lib\httpclient-4.1.3.jar;lib\httpcore-4.1.4.jar;lib\httpmime-4.1.3.jar" HttpSubmitter.java

#### Using:

> java -cp lib\httpclient-4.1.3.jar;lib\httpmime-4.1.3.jar;lib\httpcore-4.1.4.jar;lib\httpcore-4.1.4.jar;lib\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;lib\commons-codec-1.4.jar;. HttpSubmitter "Username" textfile1.txt textfile2.txt ... textfilen.txt

#### Source:

This file uploads some files to a web server, and the returned string is a url which is then opened in internet explorer.

```
import java.io.File;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpVersion;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.ContentBody;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.CoreProtocolPNames;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class HttpSubmitter {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String username = null;
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
    MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
    int counter = 0;
    for (String filename: args) {
        // First parameter passed will be the username, the rest are files.
        if (username == null) {
            username = filename;
        } else {
            // Attach file contents to the message
            File file = new File(filename);
            ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file, "text/plain");
            mpEntity.addPart("userfile" + ++counter, cbFile);

        }
    }
    ContentBody cbUsername = new StringBody(username);
    mpEntity.addPart("username", cbUsername);
    String url = "http://example.com/endpoint";
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
    httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);
    System.out.println("executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

    System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
    if (resEntity != null) {
        // Returned string will be a URL, we pass it as a url to internet explorer
        // Please keep in mind the security implications of parsing a parameter you don't control to internet explorer.
        String confirmation_page = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
        String ie = "\"C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe\" " + confirmation_page;
        // Runtime.getRuntime().exec(ie);
        System.out.println(confirmation_page);

    }
    if (resEntity != null) {
        resEntity.consumeContent();
    }

    httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to send a POST request with 'bundled' components is through PowerShell. Without knowing how you would normally send it, I can only really give a general description.

Basically, use the .NET `WebClient` class.

```
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient;
$wc.UploadString($url, "POST", $data);
```

To send the contents of a text file, read it into a variable:

```
$data = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($filename);
```

If you want to mimic submitting a web form, you need the following:

```
$wc.Headers.Add("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

That normally requires key-value pairs:

```
$data = "uploadeddata=" + [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($filename);
```

This might also help:

```
wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

Example with Pastebin API:

```
$url = "http://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php";
$filename = "test.txt";

$api_dev_key = "a Pastebin API dev key should go here";
$api_option = "paste";
$api_paste_code = [System.Uri]::EscapeDataString([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($filename));

$data = "api_dev_key=" + $api_dev_key + "&api_option=" + $api_option + "&api_paste_code=" + $api_paste_code;

$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient;
$wc.Headers.Add("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
$wc.UploadString($url, "POST", $data);
```

All this is actually based on a C# program I was writing, so there may be a shorter way. There's no real need for 'one-liners', usually.

And before anyone suggests using `Get-Content` for reading the text file, `Get-Content` returns an array with one string per line. The POST data would be harder to build from that.

Comment: Powershell doesn't come default with Windows XP, does it? I'd need to install that first before running these scripts is that correct?

Comment: @IvanKruchkoff Unfortunately, it doesn't. It's only bundled with desktop OSes Vista and later (I'm not sure about Server 2003). That's why it's probably a good idea to include Windows versions in your question.

Comment: I didn't realise the versions differed so much. I like your solution though and know other scenarios where it will come in handy, so I appreciate the answer.

Answer (score 0):

while [Download a file via HTTP from a script in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/129269/download-a-file-via-http-from-a-script-in-windows/129286#129286) was about dowloading a file from CLI you might use the same tools for uploading as well:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploadfile(v=vs.80).aspx

so, this should work (powershell):

```
$client = new-object system.net.webclient
$client.uploadFile("http://example.com", "C:\Full\Path\To\File.txt")
```